# Description of Ram Setu

Tags: ramayana, ram-setu

I am eager to know the following questions regarding Ram Setu.

1. How many days took to build Ram Setu?
2. Around How many Vanaras or monkeys were working?
3. What is the length and width of Ram Setu?
4. How old is the ram setu?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**1. How many days took to build Ramasetu?**

> 5 days

Explanation : Please check Valmiki Ramayan,
Kand: Yudhkand
Sarga:  'Sea-god advises Rama with joined palms to build a bridge

> 1st day: fourteen Yojanas

> 2nd day: twenty Yojanas

> 3rd day: twenty-one Yojanas

> 4th day: twenty-two Yojanas

> 5th day: twenty-three yojanas

**2. Around How many Vanaras or monkeys were working?**

> तानि कोटि सहस्राणि वानराणाम् महाओजसाम् |
> बध्नन्तः सागरे सेतुम् जग्मुः पारम् महाउदधेः ||

> Those **thousand crores of monkeys** in a great spectacle reached the other shore of the great ocean soon after building that bridge across the sea.

**Note:** Koti is referred for type as well. That means it can be 1000 types of monkeys as well. Also when we translate it to numbers there may be some difference in digits as described [here](http://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/kish/sarga35/kishkindha_35_frame.htm).

**3. What is the length and width of Ramasetu?**

> दशयोजनविस्तीर्णम् शतयोजन मायतम् ||
> ददृशुर्देवगन्धर्वा नलसेतुम् सुदुष्करम् |

> The celestials and Gandharvas, the heavenly musicians saw Nala's bridge, having a **width of ten yojanas** and a **length of hundred yojanas** and which was very difficult to be built.

**Note:** You have doubt here, I too used to have. But please note that the bridge was not as per ariel distance. The bridge was built at that time by Nala with the cooperation of other monkeys, of terrible doings.

**4. How old is the Ramasetu?**

Atleast  ((2400+1200)+(12000*3)+(4800+3600+2400)) divine years + 5000 human years if you consider Rama's incarnation in 24th Treta yuga (as per Vayu purana). Or atleast 2400 divine years + 5000 human years if you believe that Ram's incarnation happened in 28th Treta yuga. Few people multiply divine year by 360, few by 2 and few take it as it is. However, in my personal belief more research is needed to convert divine years to normal human years. You can file a RTI in archeological department to know the more accurate answer. Please don't forget to post here, if you get a good answer. :)

Comment: Both are mind blowing, The Ram Setu and your answer. Thanks for spending your valuable times.